# duplicate a div with children

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to clone a div with its children, I know the clone() function in jQuery, but I need to change the style of the parent div, or change the id name or show the whole div by animate, is there any way to do this?

This is the div I need to clone and I need to change the top attribute

```
<div class="news">
            <div class="meta-inform">
                <div id="waiting">not accepted</div>
                <div id="accpted">accepted</div>

                <div class="edit">
                <div class="editedBy" id="editedBy" >
                    <div id="editLabel"  style="display:inline">edited by</div>
                    <div id="editorName"  style="display:inline">arvin</div>
                </div>

                <div id="editTime" class="editTime">
                    <div id="editDate" style="display:inline" >چdate</div>
                    <div id="editDate" style="display:inline">time</div>
                </div>
                </div>

            </div>

        <div id="littleNews">
            <div id="number">1000</div>
            <div id="divider1"></div>
            <div id="title">title</div>
            <div id="divider2"></div>
            <div id="littleNewsTime">time</div>
            <div id="littleNewsDate">چdate</div>
            <div id="divider3"></div>
            <div id="category">cat</div>
            <div id="part">part</div>
            <div id="segment">sgmnt</div>
            <div id="divider4"></div>
            <div id="writer">writer</div>
            <div id="view">view post</div>
        </div>

        <div class="functions">
            <div id="edit">edit</div>
            <div id="delete">delete</div>
            <div id="accptThis">accept</div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: You can simply do all that with a cloned element, like with any other element. What is the problem? Where are you stuck? Can show some example code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use clone to **clone** the div with its children.
Use the **attr** function to change attributes.
Use the **css** function to change css attributes.

e.g.:

```
$('.news').clone().attr("id","whatever").css("width","50px")
```

Then for example, you can append it to any other container you want.
e.g.:

```
$('.news').clone().attr("id","whatever").appendTo($('body'));
```

You can also use addClass or removeClass to add/remove classes defined in your CSS files.
does that help?

Answer (score 0):

You could just add new class name and then add proper styles into css, for example:

```
$('.news').clone().addClass("clone");
```

And to the css sheet:

```
.clone {
    top: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but it works for me. Everything that needs to be done to append it to target DOM element. In the example I append cloned div to body (also cloned div highlighted in red):
[link](http://jsfiddle.net/GcStR/2/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.news').clone().attr("id","elementid").appendTo("body").animate({ 'top': '200px'}, 2000);
```